# Is there any compiled WiredTiger executable tool file for windows?

Tags: mongodb, wiredtiger

I need it to salvage Data from Corrupted MongoDB

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://source.wiredtiger.com/2.7.0/build-windows.html

Comment: thank you for your reply,I have followed the guild and got the following error:scons: Reading SConscript files ...
Checking for C header file stdlib.h... no
stdlib.h must be installed!        I've gooled but didnot find any solution